# Extracting string in `helm helper template` using regexp

Tags: regex, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I am trying to extract a certain string obtained from `values.yaml` in `_helper.tpl`. Basically, I am trying to extract the string `localhost` from `mongodb://localhost:30010`

In my `_helper.tpl`

```
{{- define "myservice.mongodbcache.bindip" -}}
{{- regexFind "\/\.(.*):" ( .Values.myservice.cachedb.uri | toString ) -}}
{{- end -}}
```

my `values.yml` file

```
myservice:
  cachedb:
    uri: "mongodb://localhost:30010"
```

and in my `configmap`, I want to use it the following way

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-myservice-configmap
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
data:
  myservice.mongodbcache.bind.ip: {{ template "myservice.mongodbcache.bindip" }}
```

However, I keep getting this error, when I try to dry run

```
Error: parse error in "tree-helm/templates/_helpers.tpl": template: tree-helm/templates/_helpers.tpl:35: invalid syntax
```

Line 35 is the one with `regexFind`

Comment: You are escaping the dot, so it will match `/.` and not `//`. Try just `//(.*):` or a bit more specific: `\w+://(.*):\d+`

Answer (score 2):

To get the host from a URL, you would need to use [Lookahead and Lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Please see the [example](https://regexr.com/46bms)

Unfortunately, you can not write this type of regex in helm. You will get the following error:

```
Error: rendering template failed: regexp: Compile(`(?<=://)(.*?)(?=:)`): error parsing regexp: invalid or unsupported Perl syntax: `(?<`
```

From [chart template guide](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/chart_template_guide/named_templates.md):

> It is considered preferable to use **include** over **template** in Helm templates simply so that the output formatting can be handled better for YAML documents.

Working with **include**, you can get the hostname or ip the following way:

**configmap.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-myservice-configmap
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
data:
  myservice.mongodbcache.bind.ip: {{- include "myservice.mongodbcache.bindip" . -}}
```

**_helpers.tpl**

```
{{- define "myservice.mongodbcache.bindip" -}}
{{- $match := .Values.myservice.cachedb.uri | toString | regexFind "//.*:" -}}
{{- $match | trimAll ":" | trimAll "/" -}}
{{- end -}}
```

Ore even have it all in one line.

**Result**

```
$ helm install --debug --dry-run .
....
# Source: mychart/templates/configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: billowing-boxer-myservice-configmap
  namespace: default
data:
  myservice.mongodbcache.bind.ip:localhost
```

Answer (score -1):

```
\/\/(.*):
```

The regex that you can use to extract the string `localhost` from `mongodb://localhost:30010`

[image]